# How to if condition then multiply in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Ive got this error message !
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== '07' || SUBSTRING(col2, 0, 3) == '447')
billsec * .06 as rate' at line 2

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
IF (SUBSTRING(col2, 0, 2) == '07' || SUBSTRING(col2, 0, 3) == '447') 
col4 * .06 as col5;
ELSE 
col4 * .03 as col5;
FROM table_name WHERE id='123'
```

but when the query is just this

```
 SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
    col4 * .06 as col5
    FROM table_name WHERE id='123'
```

it returns no error.. Can someone please let me know how to manage that?

Comment: it should be = instead of == and THEN is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
IF(SUBSTRING(col2, 1, 2) = '07' OR SUBSTRING(col2, 1, 3) = '447' , col4 * .06  , col4 * .03  ) AS col5
FROM table_name WHERE id='123';
```

in mysql there are also another version of if...else 
`IF(CONDITION ,IF_CONTDITION_TRUE, ELSE_PART)`

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f8e8/29)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== '07' || SUBSTRING(col2, 0, 3) == '447') THEN col4 * .06 as col5 ELSE col4' at line 2

Comment: i updated my answer now check if you also get error let me know

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='07' || SUBSTRING(col2, 0, 3) = '447') THEN col4 * .06 as col5 ELSE col4' at line 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104855/discussion-between-vipin-jain-and-bee).